# Regex to tokenize a string into array of numeric and alphanumeric strings in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a few strings for which I want to tokenize

for example:

```
123ae4rf468 to be split into [123,ae4rf,468] 
878768stb4hgbjh354 to be split into [878768,stb4hgbjh,354]
```

I tried below but did not work. Kindly, help

```
 def groupStrings(): Unit ={
    val pattern: Regex = "\"[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])\"".r
    for(patternMatch <- pattern.findAllMatchIn("12341abc1234"))
      println(patternMatch.groupCount)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
(^\d+)(.*?)(?<=[a-z])(\d+)$
```

- `(^\d+)` - Matches digits at start of string
- `(.+?)` - Match anything except new line one or more time
- `(?<=[a-z])(\d+)$` - Positive lookbehind matches digits preceded by character at end of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tmyZZX/2/)

On side note:- If you don't need groups you can change to this

```
^\d+.*?(?<=[a-z])\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `(\d+|\D+)`
or `(\D+(?:\d*\D)*|\d+)`
or `(\D+(?:\d*\D+)?|\d+)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).